# How to extract unique strings from a macro?

Tags: regex, stata, stata-macros

I'm trying to automate a `reshape` using Stata.

I have a series of variables measured yearly. They are all named `varname_yy`, where `yy` is a number referring to the year of measurement. I managed to extract all the stubs `varname_` from the variables and to put them into a macro using the following code:

```
local stubs
foreach var of varlist `myvars' {
local stub = substr("`var'",1,length("`var'") - 2)
    local stubs `stubs' `stub'
}
```

The problem is that I end up with many repeated stubs in the `stubs` macro and this causes `reshape` to return an error message.

In R I would just ask for `unique(stubs)`, but I couldn't find any such function in Stata.

My tentative solution is to do the following:

```
local uniquestubs
foreach stub in `stubs' {
    if !regexm("`uniquestubs'","`stub'") {
        local uniquestubs "`uniquestubs'" " `stub'"
    }
}
```

However, I can't get rid of the duplicates.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: See `help macrolists` or http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?macrolists.

Comment: You can omit the last two characters of a string by `substr("string", 1, length("string") - 2)`. That is easier than applying `reverse()` twice.

Comment: I made your suggested change to the code, so that people who see the question later on learn the better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roberto Ferrer's comment to my question led me to the answer. Turns out that all I had to do was to use the following line:

```
 local uniquestubs: list uniq stubs
```

Unlike syntax for evaluating macros, manipulating macros requires the macro names, so I should not enclose `stubs` in `` ` `` and `'` as it is usually done.

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your quote marks. They were difficult to read, in my opinion.

Comment: It looks much better now. I'll try to pay attention to that next time.